# How to fix google coral devboard ssh connection issue

Tags: ssh, google-coral, mdt

I have been using the Google Coral Devboard in a project for a while.
Today, I am surprised to see that using ssh does not work. Something went wrong somewhere.
`ssh mendel@192.168.0.111` gives

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.111 port 22: Connection refused`

`mdt devices` does find the device though. `mdt shell` does not work due to the inherent failure of ssh connection.

I have checked the `authorized_keys` file and my own private keys and they match.

I can only connect to the devboard using Serial communication.
I wish to reflash the entire thing and reset the board. However, after using `sudo reboot-bootloader`, `fastboot devices` sees nothing.

I have tried 4 USB C cables. I have tried using `fastboot 0` from the Serial console immediately instead of letting the board boot up. Nothing shows up.

I tried using Windows 10 and WSL yet nothing is showing up.

I just want to either fix the ssh connection issue or simply factory reset the entire thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That' odd, it maybe because the board disconnection from the network.
For the ssh/mdt issue, can you share this outputs:

```
$ nmcli connection show
```

Regarding fastboot issue, what if you try to initiate fastboot with an [sdcard like this](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/reflash/#flash-from-u-boot-on-an-sd-card)?

Comment: I initiated it with an sdcard and it worked! Also I was using Windows at first, but after using Linux the connection worked out. Thank you.